# Can't have many to one relationship for list intention

Tags: django, foreign-keys

I would like to add many `Agent` to `PricingOption` in a `list` fashion.

```
class PricingOption(models.Model):
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    agents = models.ForeignKey("Agent", related_name='%(class)s_agent')
```

Is the `model` that contains the `list`. The list objects themselves are

```
class Agent(models.Model):
    agent_id = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    ...
```

Now when I try to do things like

```
pricing_option = PricingOption()
pricing_option.agents_set.add(some_agent)
```

I get `*** AttributeError: 'PricingOption' object has no attribute 'agents_set'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ForeignKey` means that every single `PricingOption` will have exactly one `Agent` associated with it. It is 1-to-many relationship.

If you want to reverse this relationship, you should make `ForeignKey` to `PricingOption` in `Agent`.

If you want many-to-many relationship, you should look up `ManyToManyField`:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

EDIT:

```
class PricingOption(models.Model):
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

class Agent(models.Model):
    agent_id = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    pricing_option = models.ForeignKey("PricingOption")
```

Then pricing option on a `Agent a` will be accessible by `a.pricing_option` and agents on a `PricingOption po` by `po.agent_set`.

Comment: I understand. What model field do I use for `agents` in `PricingOption` then?

Comment: It depends entirely on the scope of your application. If 1 Agent should be associated with 1 PricingOption and 1 PricingOption with many Agents, then use `ForeignKey`. If 1 Agent with many PricingOptions and 1 PricingOption with many Agents, then use `ManyToManyField`. More info on `ER-diagram` (Entity-Relation).

Comment: So basically your solution is already what I posted? Because I want one `PricingOption` to have many `Agents` and each `Agent` only one `PricingOption`.

Comment: No, my solution is to reverse your dependancy (see edit). `ForeignKey` is just a number, an `id` of the associated pricing option.

Comment: Yes but what do `modelField`-type to I take for `agents` in `PricingOption` then?

Comment: You don't need to. The reverse name is automatically accessible by `%foreign_key_model%_set` name as in my edit: `agent_set`. You can specify your own desired name with the `related name` option though.